# iOS Using GLKMathUnproject to find screen point in world space

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

How to use GLKMathUnproject to determine location in world space?
The user needs to select one of several objects in world space.

In doc it says

```
GLKVector3 GLKMathUnproject (
   GLKVector3 window,
   GLKMatrix4 model,
   GLKMatrix4 projection,
   int *viewport,
   bool *success
);
```

but which modelView matrix? I have bunch of models in world. Which model matrix should i use.

My world is 2d, on x,y plane. z is used for camera movement.

If i understood correctly, `GLKMathUnproject` is used to find a point in model space.
How do i know which model? Do i need to determine first the model below the fingers or what?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/171432-gluUnProject-How-to-use-it-in-a-proper-way?p=1204188&viewfull=1#post1204188) at opengl website

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)handleTapUnproject:(id)recognizer
{    
    bool success = NO;
    GLfloat realY;

    GLint viewport[4] = {};
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d, %d", viewport[0], viewport[1], viewport[2], viewport[3]);

    CGPoint touchOrigin = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"tap coordinates: %8.2f, %8.2f", touchOrigin.x, touchOrigin.y);

    realY = viewport[3] - touchOrigin.y;

    GLKMatrix4 modelView = lookAt;

    // near

    GLKVector3 originInWindowNear = GLKVector3Make(touchOrigin.x, realY, 0.0f);

    GLKVector3 result1 = GLKMathUnproject(originInWindowNear, modelView, projectionMatrix, viewport, &success);
    NSAssert(success == YES, @"unproject failure");

    GLKMatrix4 matrix4_1 = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, result1.x, result1.y, 0.0f);
    _squareUnprojectNear.modelMatrixUsage = GLKMatrix4Multiply(matrix4_1, _squareUnprojectNear.modelMatrixBase);

    GLKVector3 rayOrigin = GLKVector3Make(result1.x, result1.y, result1.z);

    // far

    GLKVector3 originInWindowFar = GLKVector3Make(touchOrigin.x, realY, 1.0f);

    GLKVector3 result2 = GLKMathUnproject(originInWindowFar, modelView, projectionMatrix, viewport, &success);
    NSAssert(success == YES, @"unproject failure");

    GLKMatrix4 matrix4_2 = GLKMatrix4Translate(GLKMatrix4Identity, result2.x, result2.y, 0.0f);

    GLKVector3 rayDirection = GLKVector3Make(result2.x - rayOrigin.x, result2.y - rayOrigin.y, result2.z - rayOrigin.z);
}
```

So if you want to unproject to world space, you use just your lookAt matrix.
And if you want to unproject into model space of a specific object, then you use `model * view` matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Create simple project, which you be able to create from templates of Xcode, called "OpenGL Game".

model -  *modelViewMatrix* or *self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix*

projection - *projectionMatrix* or *self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix*

Viewport:

```
GLint viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
```

Your code will be similar to:

```
GLKVector point = ...;
bool boolValue;    
GLKMathUnproject(point,
                         modelViewMatrix,
                         projectionMatrix, viewport, &boolValue);
```

Comment: Ok, but which model matrix? That i cant grasp. Is that model matrix of camera or of some object?

Comment: it's which you putting to shader for last reposition.

Comment: No man, its not that. It is just a regular view matrix that i use everywhere. `GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(view_x, view_y, view_z, view_x, view_y, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);` That's what works for me.

Comment: It's lookAt matrix for my 2d world. `view_x`, `view_y`, `view_z` are parameters which control camera position. User input modifies those parameters.